# SwiftUI: animate changes that depend on @ObjectBinding

Tags: swiftui, combine

SwiftUI has implicit animations with `.animate()`, and explicit ones using `.withAnimation()`. However, I can't figure out how to animate an image change:

```
struct ImageViewWidget : View {
  @ObjectBinding var imageLoader: ImageLoader

  init(imageURL: URL) {
    imageLoader = ImageLoader(imageURL: imageURL)
  }

  var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage:
      (imageLoader.data.count == 0) ? UIImage(named: "logo-old")! :  UIImage(data: imageLoader.data)!)
        .resizable()
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .frame(width: 120, height:120)
  }
}
```

This `Image`'s `uiImage` argument is passed the `old-logo` (placeholder) if there's no data in `imageLoader` (a `BindableObject`), and replaces it with the correct one once that's asynchronously loaded:

```
class ImageLoader : BindableObject {
  let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Data, Never>()

  var data = Data() {
    didSet {
      didChange.send(data)
    }
  }

  init(imageURL: URL) {
    print("Image loader being initted!")
    let url = imageURL

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
      guard let data = data else { return }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.data = data
      }
      }.resume()

  }
}
```

How can I animate this change, the moment where `data.count` stops being `0`, and we have the image? say I want a fade out-in animation..

Comment: In your image loader try setting `withAnimation { yourDataVariable = data } `

Comment: but where? there's no UI there (I'm adding the code for `ImageLoader`)

Comment: You can still do that

Comment: You seem to be sure. Can you post an answer then so I can test, vote, and accept?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use explicit animations based on environment objects (or observable objects), you need to create some state in your view.

You can react to changes to an observable in your view using `onReceive`, and then modify your state using explicit animation.

```swift
struct ImageViewWidget: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader: ImageLoader
    @State var uiImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "logo-old")!

    init(imageURL: URL) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader(imageURL: imageURL)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            .resizable()
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
            .onReceive(imageLoader.$data) { data in
                if data.count != 0 {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.uiImage = UIImage(data: data)!
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't necessarily have to call .animate() or .withAnimation() because you are simply switching the images, you can use .transition() instead.
Assuming you have already successfully updated your image with your @ObjectBinding(@ObservedObject in Beta5), you can do this:

```
var body: some View {
    if imageLoader.data.count == 0 {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "logo-old")!)
        .resizable()
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .frame(width: 120, height:120)
        .transition(.opacity)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration:1))
    } else {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: imageLoader.data)!)
        .resizable()
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .frame(width: 120, height:120)
        .transition(.opacity)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration:1))
    }
}
```

or you can use a custom view modifier if you want to make the transition fancier:

```
struct ScaleAndFade: ViewModifier {
    /// True when the transition is active.
    var isEnabled: Bool

    // fade the content view while transitioning in and
    // out of the container.
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
            .scaleEffect(isEnabled ? 0.1 : 1)
            .opacity(isEnabled ? 0 : 1)
            //any other properties you want to transition
    }
}


extension AnyTransition {
    static let scaleAndFade = AnyTransition.modifier(
        active: ScaleAndFade(isEnabled: true),
        identity: ScaleAndFade(isEnabled: false))
}
```

and then inside your `ImageViewWidget`, add `.transition(.scaleAndFade)` to your Image as its view modifier

Comment: This (your first suggestion) doesn't work. The image is immediately replaced without any effects. I also think it (somehow) makes the images load synchronously.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add ` .animation(.easeInOut(duration:1))` after .transition, works for me

Comment: It still doesn't work. Nor animation and transition takes no effect